# How can I rotate an MP4 video by 90 degrees?

Tags: java, android, video, orientation, mp4

I have tried doing the following, using mp4parser:

```
private void rotate(String videoPath) {
    IsoFile out =  new IsoFile(videoPath);
    out.getMovieBox().getMovieHeaderBox().setMatrix(Matrix.ROTATE_90);

    File outputVideo = new File(videoPath+".rotated.mp4");
    if (!outputVideo.exists())
        outputVideo.createNewFile();

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputVideo);
    out.writeContainer(fos.getChannel());
    fos.close();
    out.close();
}
```

But this only sets a flag in the header that tells the video to be played at a different orientation. What's the easiest/fastest way to actually rotate the video?

Comment: MP4 is just a container format, to actually rotate the frames in the stream you would need to modify the data; this might required decoding and re-encoding; or some tricky re-arranging of the data (depending on codec). No way around parsing the actual frame data.

Comment: @Durandal, I am OK with trying this. I know encoding can take a while, but I can set up a background service for this.